# PrimeNG DataTable - contextMenu is off centered when wrapped in a TabView

Tags: css, angular, primeng

I enchanted a problem displaying a DataTable - contextMenu when it is within a TabView. The contextMenu would appear off centered.  The DataTable - contextMenu works when it is not wrapped in a TabView.

I filed an issue on the PrimeNG GitHub site https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/1090

Here is an image of a screenshot.
[image]

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem but managed to solve it by adding appendTo="body" to context menu component as below:

```
<p-contextMenu #cxtMenu [model]="ctxtMenuItems" appendTo="body" ></p-contextMenu>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add appendTo="body" to context menu component it should solve it

Answer (score 0):

## Possible Solution

I was able to correct this issue by overriding the ui-tabview's position

```
.ui-tabview {
    position: initial;
}
```